# Cast sympy boolean expression to sympy integer

Tags: python, type-conversion, sympy

Let's say I want to build an integer from some separated boolean values applying some boolean logic

In pure python I can do something like this.

```py
as_flags = lambda x1, x2, x3, y: x3 + 2 * (x2 | y) + 4 * x1 
as_flags(True, False, True, True)  # 0b111
```

But when I try to have this integer as a `sympy` formula:

```py
x1, x2, x3, y = symbols('x1 x2 x3 y')
flags = x3 + 2 * (x2 | y) + 4 * x1
```

I get: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'Or'`

`sympy.core.compatibility.as_int` seems not to be helpful here as well.

Is there any correct way to do such conversion?

---

**UPD:** Of course, as a cumbersome workaround there is always an option  to avoid SymPy's boolean implementation and to reinvent the bicycle of boolean algebra:

```py
from sympy.core import Symbol, Mod, Add, Mul

def _or(self, other):
        return (self + other + self * other) % 2

def _and(self, other):
    return (self * other) % 2

def _xor(self, other):
    return (self + other) % 2

def _not(self):
    return (self + 1) % 2

class IntegerBoolean(Symbol):
    __or__, __and__ = _or, _and
    __xor__, __invert__ =  _xor, _not

for cls in (Mod, Add, Mul):
    cls.__invert__ = _not
    cls.__ror__ = _or
    cls.__radd__ = _and
    cls.__rxor__ = _xor


x1, x2, x3, y = [IntegerBoolean(t) for t in ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'y']]
flags = x3 + 2*(x2 | y) + 4*x1

print(flags)
# 4*x1 + x3 + 2*Mod(x2*y + x2 + y, 2)

print(bin(flags.subs({x1: 1, x2: 0, x3: 1, y: 1})))
# 0b111
```

But I hope there is a more proper way to handle this.

Comment: SymPy chooses not to conflate Boolean with Integer in the way that Python does. It's a mistake in Python IMO.